# BehaviorSubject next not defined

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, rxjs

I am getting runtime error when i set next(..) on a BehaviorSubject that is a firebase.User | null type.

```
subscribe.js:165 TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined
```

Here is the code thats causing the issue.

```
export class AppAuthService {

   private currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<firebase.User |null>(null);
   public currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable().distinctUntilChanged();

   private isAuthenticatedSubject = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1);
   public isAuthenticated = this.isAuthenticatedSubject.asObservable();

   constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
      afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(this.onAuthStateChanged);
    }

    onAuthStateChanged(user: firebase.User): void {
      if (user) {
        this.currentUserSubject.next(user);    <------err
        this.isAuthenticatedSubject.next(true);
        console.log('loggedIN!');
      } else {
        this.currentUserSubject.next(null);   <-------err
        this.isAuthenticatedSubject.next(false);
        console.log('GONE!');
      }
   }

}
```

The error shows up anytime when `this.currentUserSubject.next(..)` is set to a user obj or null. I suspect its because the currentUserSubject is initialized with null and next of null is wrong?...

```
private currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<firebase.User |null>(null);
```

I am not able to initialize it with `new firebase.User()` because its an interface and not an object.

Also declaring currentUserSubject as subject results in same error.

```
private currentUserSubject = new Subject();
```

What is the best way to convert the firebase.User interface into a Subject/ReplaySubject? I am trying to do this so that when user changes something on profile component it will dynamic update on firebase server.

Thanks.

Comment: Your error doesn't make sense. I tried here and it works: https://plnkr.co/edit/etWUx93vtQkfp0mkhbnU?p=preview Are you sure you don't have a method `set currentUserSubject(v) {` somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use fat arrow functions:

```
constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
  afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => this.onAuthStateChanged(user));
}
```